# How can I tell JWebUnit to contact specific Selenium servers

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, integration-testing

We want to run selenium backed jwebunit tests from our hudson server. We have a couple of selenium rc servers already on our network which I'd like to reuse.

However, how can I configure jwebunit to use those servers as I would like to avoid installing a slenium rc server on the hudson. Building is already work enough without starting/stopping firefoxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried Selenium Grid and then you just point your tests at the Selenium Grid Hub and your tests never have to know where the Selenium Remote Control servers are.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Comment: Thank you. We added it to our to do list of things to set up on our build server. Currently we worked around this issue by using HtmlUnit and running selenium on our development machines.
I see that this solution will also help us in running against multiple browsers : 2 birds with 1 stone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as far as i can see it cannot be done immediately : it is hardcoded in the implementation.

```
public void beginAt(URL aInitialURL, TestContext aTestContext) throws TestingEngineResponseException {
    this.setTestContext(aTestContext);
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", port, "*chrome", aInitialURL.toString());
    selenium.start();
    gotoPage(aInitialURL);
}
```